# How to calculate row values in a column in pyspark dataframe, using the previously calculated values in the same column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and I want to calculate row values in a column based on previously calculated values in the same column, and this needs to work with newly calculated rows as well.

Right now I am using lag() but it is doing the required task only once, it needs to be done for all the rows.

Inv = (previous) inv - (current) sup + (current) unit

[image: Sample and expected dataset]

```
windowPartition = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("year", "month")
df=df.withColumn("Lag_inv",F.lag("inv", 1).over(windowPartition))
su=F.col("Lag_inv")-F.col("inv")+F.col("units")
df=df.withColumn('sup', F.round(su, 2)).drop("Lag_ai")
```

the code that I am using, but it is not working

Comment: The first two records doesn't need any calculation right, since it was prefilled?

Comment: yes correct. some data will be there, it need not be touched upon. 

we can have a separate column that specifies which rows are going to have data already